# highlight keywords in a chatbox, how to add different styles to several keywords?

Tags: javascript, arrays, userscripts

I'm editing a userscript that has a highlight function inside a chat box on a gaming site. I'm trying to make it so I can add keywords and different css styles to it. I'm looking for something that adds keywords into groups, so that I can make one style to several keywords in that group. And a different style to another group.

This is how it looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YEyH.png

```
dctools.checkForChatKeyword = function(elements) {
    if (GM_getValue("dct-options-hiflags") != null) {
        $(elements).highlight('flag')

            .highlight('keyword 1') 
            .highlight('keyword 2')
            .highlight('keyword 3')
            .highlight('keyword 4')
            .highlight('keyword 5')
            .highlight('keyword 6')
            .highlight('keyword 7');
    }
```

Is there a simple way to add css styles to these different keywords using arrays?

Comment: Will each keyword appear in its own element? You could assign a `word` attribute which matches a CSS rule, e.g. `<kw word='hello'>hello</kw>`

Comment: Yes and no. Some keywords are preferred to be assigned within a group of keywords. Let's say I want:

example
 ('apple', 'shoes', 'numbers').css("color"),("#F2F56G");

Then another group of keywords: 

('look at the flowers', 'claimed').css("color"),("#F2F56G");

maybe using array to smack all the keywords I want to appear '#FGHIJH' into one. But I don't know how or where to begin with the code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *general*, (since you don't show the `.highlight` function code) you would:

1. Create a series of jQuery style objects, like:

   ```
   var
       styleRedOnYellow  = {"color": "red",     "background": "yellow"}
     , styleWhiteOnBlack = {"color": "white",   "background": "black"}
     , styleLimeOnPink   = {"color": "lime",    "background": "pink"}
     , stylePuke_1       = {"color": "#EEF272", "background": "#97CC9A"}
   ;
   ```
2. Then you can link keywords with styles using an *associative array*:

   ```
   var stylePerKeyword             = [];
   stylePerKeyword["keyword 1"]    = styleRedOnYellow;
   stylePerKeyword["apple"]        = styleRedOnYellow;
   stylePerKeyword["keyword 3"]    = styleLimeOnPink;
   stylePerKeyword["keyword 4"]    = styleLimeOnPink;
   stylePerKeyword["shoes"]        = stylePuke_1;
   ```
3. Then inside the `.highlight` function, it can apply the styles to the wrapping nodes something like so:

   ```
   /*--- keywordParameter is the variable inside highlight() that 
       contains the particular keyword for this function call.
   */
   var styleToApply    = stylePerKeyword[keywordParameter];
   if (styleToApply) {
       /*-- wrappingNode is a jQuery around whatever highlight()
           wraps a word in to highlight it with. Probably a <span>.
       */
       wrappingNode.css (styleToApply);
   }
   else {
       console.log (
           '*** Unknown keyword, "' + keywordParameter 
           + '", in .highlight()'
       );
   }
   ```